# Arrange a two dimensional array based on some of the items in the first dimension

Tags: javascript

I have a two dimensional array. Not all items in each dimension are similar but I want to make sure that those in the second array are located in the same location as the first one.

so for example :

```
array = [
    ["Jessica", "Ashley", "Emily", "Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor"]
    ["Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor", "Hannah", "Brittany", "Amanda"]
]
```

should be turned into:

```
array = [
   ["Jessica", "Ashley", "Emily", "Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor"]
   ["Hannah", "Brittany", "Amanda","Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor"]
]
```

Any suggestions?

Notice **its important to retain the original location of the names in the first array and not just sort everything to the end**

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: iterate over the 2nd array, if you find the element in the first array, swap it with the element of the matching index in the second array.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have a [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method that takes a function. In that function you can lookup the index of the name with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in the first array and sort on that:

```js
let arr = [
    ["Jessica", "Ashley", "Emily", "Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor"],
    ["Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor", "Hannah", "Brittany", "Amanda"]
]

arr[1].sort((a, b) => arr[0].indexOf(a) - arr[0].indexOf(b))

console.log(arr[1])
```

This is not very efficient — it has to look through the first array many times just to sort the second. If you had a lot of values and the first version became a bottleneck, you could create a lookup that mapped keys to indexes of the first array:

```js
let arr = [
    ["Jessica", "Ashley", "Emily", "Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor"],
    ["Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor", "Hannah", "Brittany", "Amanda"]
]

let lookup = arr[0].reduce((lookup, name, index) => {
    lookup[name] = index
    return lookup
}, {})

// when name is not in lookup use -1 to make them sort first
arr[1].sort((a, b) => (lookup[a] || -1) - (lookup[b] || -1))

console.log(arr[1])
```

**Edit**

To keep the same index rather than just the same sort order, you can iterate over the first array and swap the placement of the second. This insures that you alway place earlier items in the correct location first so you don't reswap them:

```js
let arr = [["Jessica", "Ashley", "Emily", "Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor"], ["Hannah", "Brittany", "Amanda", "Ashley", "Samantha", "Taylor"]]

arr[0].forEach((item , i)=> {
    let index = arr[1].indexOf(item);
    if (index >= 0){
        [arr[1][i], arr[1][index]] = [arr[1][index], arr[1][i]]

    }
})

console.log(arr[1])
```

Comment: the sort code pushes all the matches to the end of the array. for example if we have a arr= [["Jessica", "Ashley", "Emily", "Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor"],
 ["Hannah", "Brittany", "Amanda", "Ashley", "Samantha", "Taylor"]]  - the sort would not keep the original place but merely put all the matched names at the end. Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: @chagag for some reason I though you just needed the same sort order. See edit.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first array and store that in a variable (`let first_arr = arr[0]`). You can then iterate over all inner arrays and check if the index of a given array matches the one in the first array by using `first_array.indexOf()`. If it doesn't match you need to swap the two values around.

See working example below (read code comments for explanation):

```js
let arr = [["Jessica", "Ashley", "Emily", "Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor"],
  ["Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor", "Hannah", "Brittany", "Amanda"]];


let first_arr = arr[0]; // get the first array as the "base" array

for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) { // loop over the 2d array
  let current_arr = arr[i]; // get the current array and store in in a variable
  for (let j = 0; j < current_arr.length; j++) { // loop over each index in the current array
    let name = current_arr[j]; // get the name at a given index in the array
    let nameIndex = first_arr.indexOf(name); // get the index of the name in the first array
    if (nameIndex > -1 && nameIndex != j) { // check if the name is in the correct position already. (Also if nameIndex == -1 then it doesn't exsist in the original array)
      // If the name isn't in the correct index position then SWAP the values around:
      let tmp = current_arr[j];
      current_arr[j] = current_arr[nameIndex];
      current_arr[nameIndex] = tmp;
    }
  }
}

console.log(arr); // log the modified array
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately that doesn't work. For the array -[ ["Jessica", "Ashley", "Emily", "Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor"],  ["Ashley", "Samantha", "Taylor", "Hannah", "Brittany", "Amanda"]] the code produces this array: [["Jessica", "Ashley", "Emily", "Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor"], ["Samantha", "Ashley", "Amanda", "Hannah", "Brittany", "Taylor"]] the order is not the same. It only works well with the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two loops if the dept is just 2.

```js
let array = [
  ["Jessica", "Ashley", "Emily", "Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor"],
  ["Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor", "Hannah", "Brittany", "Amanda"]
];

/** Loop through the inner array */
for (let i in array[1]) {
  /** Check to see if the outer array contains the value */
  let index = array[0].indexOf(array[1][i])
  /** If it does swap it's location */
  if (index > -1) {
    let temp = array[1][index];
    array[1][index] = array[1][i]
    array[1][i] = temp
  }
}
console.log(array)
```

Output should be

[ [ 'Jessica', 'Ashley', 'Emily', 'Samantha', 'Sarah', 'Taylor' ],
  [ 'Hannah', 'Brittany', 'Amanda', 'Samantha', 'Sarah', 'Taylor' ] ]

Comment: Thank you for this code. To my best knowledge that only works if the three are clustered.  For example if I run your code on this: array = [
  ["Jessica", "Ashley", "Emily", "Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor"],
  ["Samantha", "Sarah", "Hannah",  "Taylor","Brittany", "Amanda"]
]; it down't work

Comment: I did - try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
                array = [
                    ["Jessica", "Ashley", "Emily", "Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor"],
                    ["Samantha", "Sarah", "Taylor", "Hannah", "Brittany", "Amanda"]
                ]

                size = array.length
                size1 = array[0].length

                document.write(size1);


                for(var i=0; i<size1; i++){
                  for(var j=0; j<size1; j++){
                    if(array[0][i] == array[1][j] ){
                      var x = array[1][j]
                      var y = array[1][i]

                      array[1][i] = x
                      array[1][j] = y
                    }
                  }
                }

                console.log(array)
```

Try this out